# convert base64 to image while not connecting to internet

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, uiimage, base64

i am implementing sqlite in my swift project and i am storing base64 string of image in sqlite table then after i am retrieving back base64 image but my scenario in that when user access offline mode of app than how to convert base64 to uiimage without internet so can anyone please tell me is their any way to convert without internet

```
let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
var decodedimage = UIImage(data: decodedData)
println(decodedimage)
imgView.image = decodedimage as UIImage
```

i am converting like this but in offline mode i am not able to convert base64 to image so please help me

Comment: How is having access to the Internet related to your question? If you already have the image data in a local database, then decode it and show it. No Internet access needed.

Comment: i don't have image data in local database i have base64 string in local data base

Comment: Same thing. The base64 string is your image data, it's just encoded.

Comment: yes but i am retrieving and converting then not able to convert thats what i mean

Comment: You need to put relevant details in your question. Simply stating "it doesn't work" isn't sufficient. Do some debugging and narrow down where the issue is. Are you able to read the string from the database? Can you convert the base64 string into a `Data` instance? Can you create a `UIImage` from the data? Are you sure you properly encoded and stored the original image into the database correctly? Put relevant details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You might have an issue with prefix **data:image/png;base64**

If the string contains **data:image/png;base64**, It  will return nil while decoding from base64.

You have to remove **data:image/png;base64** from your base64 string first, then you will get image from string.

After removing, use following code to get image:

```
if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
            let image = UIImage(data: decodedData)
            print(image)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension and thank me later :)

```
extension UIImage{
convenience init?(base64 str: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: str),
        let data = try? Foundation.Data(contentsOf: url),
        UIImage(data: data) != nil else { return nil }
    self.init(data: data)!
}
}

//self.imageView.image = base64ToImage(base64String: urlString)
```